# Preposition with noun for "faire causatif" and "laisser"

Tags: grammaire, verbes, constructions-causatives

"I will make Pierre do the dishes."

Should the translation be

> (a) Je vais faire faire la vaisselle à Pierre.
>
> (b) Je vais faire Pierre faire la vaisselle.

I think it should be (a), but two *faire*s next to each other seems strange. Is it correct?

Similarly: "I will let Pierre do the dishes."

> (c) Je vais laisser faire la vaisselle à Pierre.
>
> (d) Je vais laisser Pierre faire la vaisselle.

This time I think (d) is correct, because *laisser* takes a direct object rather than an indirect object as in the case of *faire*.

Comment: (a) and (d), yes. The other 2 do not work.

Comment: @Frank Thanks. Does two *faire*s next to each other seem strange, or is it completely normal?

Comment: I confirm **that that** is completely normal!

Comment: Yep, nothing strange in using two *faire* next to each other! As there is nothing strange with the two *nous* in ***Nous nous** entraidons pour ce travail* (although there is no grammatical link between *faire faire* and *nous nous*).

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_while_John_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_a_better_effect_on_the_teacher

Comment: @user11550 Yes but no - I mean it sounds a bit funny, but we are used to it, and it's the proper way of saying it, so it's ok.

Comment: I definitly agree with Frank, it's a very common way to express "to have someone do".

Comment: @Frank "The other 2 do not work": for me, only (d) doesn't work. But (c) is ok too, and rather common.

Comment: @cFreed - you are right - in the current form of (c), which has been edited after I made my initial comment. It used to be _je vais laisser faire Pierre la vaisselle_ or something that didn't work like that. It's been edited since, I think. I would personally prefer _je vais laisser Pierre faire la vaisselle_.

Comment: @Frank Perhaps you can turn your comments into an answer?

Comment: @user11550 - ok :-)

Comment: @user11550 - done - don't forget to select an answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (a) Je vais faire faire la vaisselle à Pierre.

does work as is in French. Those two *faire* back to back might seem strange at first, but it is correct, and we are used to it, so no problem.

> (b) Je vais faire Pierre faire la vaisselle.

That one is definitely broken. That *Pierre* between the two *faire* should not be there, although if you think about it, it's logical in a sense.

> (c) Je vais laisser faire la vaisselle à Pierre.

Is correct - nothing special here, maybe a tad cumbersome, maybe it's just me - I would prefer that *à Pierre* to not be so far at the end of the sentence. But it is correct.

> (d) Je vais laisser Pierre faire la vaisselle.

That one is correct, and probably the one I would prefer. It sounds best among those four alternatives, IMHO.